# How to get individual values from ups api address validation response through rocketshipit in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have a response for ups address validation request as follows:

```
Array ( [meta] => Array ( [code] => 200 [error_message] => ) [data] => Array ( [city] => [errors] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [code] => [type] => [description] => The state is not supported in the Customer Integration Environment. ) ) [name] => [city_state_zip_match] => [residential] => [po_box] => [suggestions] => [zipcode] => [state] => [addr2] => [addr3] => [addr1] => [zipcode_addon] => [country] => [checks] => [match] => ) )
```

in PHP, how I do I get individual values like..
 `code` and `error_message` `name`, `residential`, `po_box`, `sate` etc.

Thanks in advance

Comment: $variable['meta']['code']; // try like that where $variable is variable which hold the array

Comment: $x = $resp['meta']['code'];

it gives error like..
Warning: Illegal string offset 'meta' in ...
Warning: Illegal string offset 'code' in ...
$resp contain the above string which i received from ups

Answer (score 0):

With an array like this

```
$arr = Array([meta] => Array ( [code] => 200 [error_message] => ));
```

This is equivalent to

```
$arr = ["meta" => ["code" => 200, "error_message" => ""]];
```

So to access the `code` we would do

```
$code = $arr["meta"]["code"];
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response. you code working fine. here, I ave a variable called $resp and it contain the above string. From $resp how do i get those values?

Comment: From $resp, assuming it's an array, you can access it the same way as I posted above. If it's an object you can access it as $resp->meta

Answer (score 0):

Thank you.
It is working fine with the following code.

```
$json = <response from ups through rocketship.it>
print_r($json['meta']['code']);
print_r($json['meta']['error_message']);
print_r($json['data']['name']);
print_r($json['data']['po_box']);
print_r($json['data']['errors'][0]['description']);
if ($json['data']['po_box']){
    echo "PO BOX: Yes";
}else{
    echo "PO BOX: No";
}
```